# Regex Expression simple rewrite

Tags: php, regex, iis, web, url-rewriting

I am implementing a rewrite rule, that will be used when a user navigates to the following.

```
domain/distributor_search
```

or

`domain/distributor_search/page-2`, `3`, `4` etc.

This is my RegEx

This expression is broken up by the or operator

find word distributor_search with no white space after

or

Find any word with page-`num`

```
\b\Wdistributor_search\b\s|\b(\/page-[0-9]*)\b
```

the page-num expression works fine but find word distributor_search does not

Comment: I think you are over-complicating it by trying to use `\b` and `\W` (or misunderstanding their purpose), and to use the OR operator doesn't make sense here because actually all your `page-x` URLs also contain `distributor_search`.

Comment: you are misusing tags. Why php and iis together?

Comment: @SagarV You can run PHP on IIS: https://php.iis.net/

Comment: Thanks @BadHorsie I will update myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
distributor_search(\/page-\d+)?\/?$
```